# sequentially shorter list from the right via indexing - need [:-0] to act like [:]

Tags: python-2.7, indexing

I've abstracted my problem to something very simple. I'd like the `[:-0]` to give me `[:]` but can't see how to do it without using a special case.

I'm trying to get the behavior indicated below:

The first cases are just for completeness.

```
a = range(6)

print "a[i:] for i in range(3)"
for i in range(3):
    print a[i:]

print "a[:i] for i in range(3)"
for i in range(3):
    print a[:i]

print "a[-i:] for i in range(3)"
for i in range(3):
    print a[-i:]

print "a[:i] for i in [None, -1, -2] DESIRED RESULT"
for i in [None, -1, -2]:
    print a[:i]

print "a[:-i] for i in range(3) BUT CAN'T GET IT HERE"
for i in range(3):
    print a[:-i]

print "a[:i] for i in [0, -1, -2] OR HERE EITHER"
for i in [0, -1, -2]:
    print a[:i]
```

You can run it in 2.7 or just refer to the results below:

```
a[i:] for i in range(3)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]

a[:i] for i in range(3)
[]
[0]
[0, 1]

a[-i:] for i in range(3)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5]
[4, 5]

a[:i] for i in [None, -1, -2] DESIRED RESULT
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]

a[:-i] for i in range(3) BUT CAN'T GET IT HERE
[]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]

a[:i] for i in [0, -1, -2] OR HERE EITHER
[]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take advantage of Python's coalescing operators:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print a[:-i or None]
... 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in [0, -1, -2]:
...     print a[:i or None]
... 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: WOW! That's great! Is this relatively new? (looking at [PEP-505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/#abstract))

Comment: No. `and` and `or` have had coalescing behavior since... 1.5, at least. Any operators described in PEP 505 apply specifically to `None` rather than the truthity of the operands.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you please clarify my understanding of what's happening here? Reading up on coalescing operators, it suggests that the bool checks will continue until something is found that is True - a "default value". But `bool(None) = False` so is it in fact the case here that it has to return _something_ from the options, so returns the last option regardless of truthity if all preceding options are False?

Comment: @roganjosh: Correct.